# java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null remote kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka

I have installed kafka on three machines. I'm trying to read kafka's messages in storm using kafkaspout. I'm using this code to connect

```
    Broker brokerForPartition0 = new Broker("208.113.164.114:9091");
            Broker brokerForPartition1 = new Broker("208.113.164.115:9092");
            Broker brokerForPartition2 = new Broker("208.113.164.117:9093");
            GlobalPartitionInformation partitionInfo = new GlobalPartitionInformation();
            partitionInfo.addPartition(0, brokerForPartition0);//mapping from partition 0 to brokerForPartition0
    partitionInfo.addPartition(1, brokerForPartition1);//mapping from partition 1 to brokerForPartition1
    partitionInfo.addPartition(2, brokerForPartition2);//mapping from partition 2 to brokerForPartition2
    StaticHosts hosts = new StaticHosts(partitionInfo);
    SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, "newImageTest","", "id1");
    spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
```

The kafka configuration files are (I'm putting the most important lines)

```
############################# Server Basics #############################
# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each  broker.
broker.id=2
############################# Socket Server Settings    #############################
listeners=PLAINTEXT://208.113.164.115:9092
port=9092
# Hostname the broker will bind to. If not set, the server will bind to  all interfaces
host.name=208.113.164.115
# Hostname the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not  set, it uses the
# value for "host.name" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value  returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.host.name=208.113.164.115
# The port to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use. If this is not set,
# it will publish the same port that the broker binds to.
advertised.port=9092
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
2017-01-12T23:07:15.581+0000 b.s.util [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:98) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:83) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:149) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:77) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:67) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:83) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at storm.kafka.StaticCoordinator.<init>(StaticCoordinator.java:34) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:92) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3371$fn__3386.invoke(executor.clj:529) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__460.invoke(util.clj:461) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Any help Please!

Comment: The exception complains it tried to read data from a closed socket. Could you make sure the Kafka servers are all started successfully and make them connectable?

Comment: I have used the consumer command line of apache kafka and was able to read all the messages

Comment: Did you use new consumer or old consuemr for the ConsoleConsumer?

Comment: I'm using this command:
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 208.113.164.114:2181 --topic ImageTest --from-beginning

Comment: Could you try this command: bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 208.113.164.114:9091,208.113.164.115:9092,208.113.164.117:9093 --topic ImageTest --from-beginning

Comment: Yes, I'm getting data
this command is also working

Comment: Make sure your storm machines could ping kafka brokers via IP, hostname and FQDN and check /etc/hosts for that.

Comment: I have installed Apache storm and apache kafka on the same machines. and I have updated /etc/hosts but still doesn't work

Comment: Was this issue solved? @RiHab